# Where can I find all United States' railroad & subway station list and its passenger usage of each station?

Tags: usa, traffic

I have been searching for a list of all (or atleast a significant list of say top 1000 of) **United States' railroad & subway station** with its passenger usage of each station. Where can I find such information. Is there a single open source dataset that contains the information that I need or do I need to combine information from multiple sources? Any guidance on where and how to put together such data will be very helpful?